# TYPO3 TCA type select static_info_tables in FLUID?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

i use for a TYPO3 TCA Backend Country Selector, a type select and the EXT: static_info_tables // static_info_tables_de

it work in the backend perfect. I have here a country-Select:

```
'land' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Land',
    'displayCond' => 'EXT:static_info_tables_de:LOADED:true',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => array(
            array('', 0)
        ),
        'foreign_table' => 'static_countries',
        'allowNonIdValues' => TRUE,
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY static_countries.cn_short_de',
        'itemsProcFunc' => 'SJBR\\StaticInfoTables\\Hook\\Backend\\Form\\FormDataProvider\\TcaSelectItemsProcessor->translateCountriesSelector',
        //'itemsProcFunc_config' => array(
        //    'indexField' => 'cn_short_de',
        //),
        'size' => 1,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'default' => '54', // Default Germany value="54"
        'eval' => 'required'
    )
),
```

the FE Debug output is = `land => '54' (2 chars)`
But, i do not know, how I change the ID in the Country-Name?

here is the Model - Code:

```
/**
 * Land
 *
 * @var string
 *
 */
protected $land = '';

/**
 * Returns the land
 *
 * @return string $land
 */
public function getLand() {
    return $this->land;
}

/**
 * Sets the land
 *
 * @param string $land
 * @return void
 */

public function setLand($land) {
    $this->land = $land;
}
```

i found this example for a FE Select-Form, but i need the right "Country"-Name not a FORM-Selector.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/static_info_tables/ExtbaseDomainModel/UsingTheModel/AddingACountrySelectFieldToAForm/Index.html

i think, i dont need the "string".. i need this:

```
@param \SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Repository\CountryRepository $land
```

thanks for help!
Sebastian

Comment: Are you using extbase?

Answer (score 3):

What you most likely want to do, is establish a proper relation in your domain model. You already set the relation in the TCA, so adapt your model:

```
/**
 * @var \SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country
 */
protected $land = '';

/**
 * @return \SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country $land
 */
public function getLand() {
    return $this->land;
}

/**
 * @param \SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country $land
 * @return void
 */  
public function setLand(\SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country $land) {
    $this->land = $land;
}
```

The static info tables extension already told extbase how to map the database table to the `\SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country` model.
So after this change you should be able to fetch the name of the country.

```
$model->getLand()->getOfficialNameLocal();
```

You can check the model to see what getters are now available for you.